# Jumbled Kannada fonts in pdf report usingdompdf and php

Tags: php, dompdf

[ಹೌದು ಯಾರಲ್ಲಿ it should display like this while rendering from dompdf.

here is my code.. I  have used noto sans kannada regular font

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADeiA.png)

ಹೌದು ಯಾರಲ್ಲಿ     text should display like this

```
<?php reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('enable_remote', TRUE);

$dompdf->set_option('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);

$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html,'UTF-8');


// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');//or landscape

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream($filename, array('Attachment'=>0));
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream($filename);

//direct download

//$dompdf->stream("quotation.pdf", array("Attachment" => true))

  
?>
```

Comment: so there is a bracket? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the font from Google Fonts and add it to Dompdf.

later add this to your code, dont forget to change the font path and filename.

```
$dompdf->set_option('font_path', '/fonts/kannadafont.ttf');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I gave it a try.however, the problem has not been resolved